# Can't read integers from File one by one correctly

Tags: c, file, scanf

In my case I can print the 50 4digits random generated numbers into the file named **rastgele.txt** but then ı need to read them from file one by one and store them in the array named **dosyaOkuma[]** and print them to the screen. But when ım try to scan and print them ı get irrelevant numbers so ı cant read them correctly from file. I need some help about reading int numbers from file correctly.

Here is my File format:

`2862  3232  2869  2993  1303  3799  2257  2296  2105  3502  1318  3348  1851  3741  1468  1605  1994  1005  2211  1646  3056  3319  2273  1436  2621  1882  3856  2869  2026  2789  2055  1205  1263  1051  3059  3275  2876  1703  3674  1539  2381  2513  2415  3613  1066  3796  2710  2578  1294  3255`

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
   FILE *file;
   int sayilar[50];
   int dosyaOkuma[50];
   int i,x,y;
   srand ( time(NULL) );
   for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
       int num = (rand() % 2999) +1000;
       sayilar[i] = num;
   }
   file = fopen("rastgele.txt","w");
   for(x=0;x<50;x++){
   fprintf(file,"%d  ",sayilar[x]);
   }
   printf("Olusuturulan rastgele sayilar rastgele.txt dosyasina yazdirildi...");

   for(y=0;y<50;y++){
   fscanf(file,"%d",&dosyaOkuma[y]);               //where ı read file...
   printf("\n%d. sayi = %1d",y+1,dosyaOkuma[y]);   //where ı print files to screen...
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And here is my program output:

```
1. sayi = 101
2. sayi = 0
3. sayi = -285212433
4. sayi = 32765
5. sayi = 0
6. sayi = 0
7. sayi = 0
8. sayi = 0
9. sayi = 0
10. sayi = 0
11. sayi = -1697181492
...
```

Comment: I changed **w+** istead of **w** but ı get same outputs :(

Comment: For the reading, you need to go back to the beginning of the file. C I/O function only have a single "position", and when you attempt to read it's at the end of what you've written.

Comment: On another note, you don't need an array when reading, only a single `int` variable.

Comment: ı see, so how should ı refactor my code ?

Comment: sorry , ı got same outputs :(

Answer (score 1):

Include `stdio.h` and `time.h`
Add `rewind` after writing and before reading.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main ( void){
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int sayilar[50] = { 0};
    int dosyaOkuma[50] = { 0};
    int i = 0, x = 0, y= 0;
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int num = (rand() % 2999) +1000;
        sayilar[i] = num;
    }
    if ( NULL != ( file = fopen("rastgele.txt","w+"))) {
        for ( x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
            fprintf ( file,"%d  ",sayilar[x]);
        }
        printf ( "Olusuturulan rastgele sayilar rastgele.txt dosyasina yazdirildi...");
        rewind ( file);
        for ( y = 0; y < 50; y++) {
            if ( 1 == fscanf(file,"%d",&dosyaOkuma[y])) {
                printf("\n%d. sayi = %1d",y+1,dosyaOkuma[y]);
            }
        }
        fclose ( file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yesss you saved my day mann, I'm greatfull !!